# How to optimize Firebase Analytics start up?

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have Firebase Analytics and Remote Config pods installed.

When changing the phone's region (or restarting my phone) and starting my app again, the remote config `fetchAndActivate` takes more time to complete. (5 to 10 sec! instead of < 2sec)

After some investigation, I found that if I remove the firebase analytics pod, I don't see that issue anymore!

What I understand is the Analytics will be started by Firebase Core when calling `FirebaseApp.configure`

Question:

- Is there a way to post pone Analytics startup and fetching or has it running in the background so it will not affect the rest of my app?
- Does using Google Analytics instead of Firebase Analytics could solve the issue or we are talking about the same thing (there is a different pod for Google Analytics)?

Here the code that takes more time to complete.

```
private func setupRemoteConfig(completionHandler: @escaping (_ error: Error?) -> Void) {

    let remoteConfigSettings = RemoteConfigSettings()
    var fetchInterval: TimeInterval = 0

    remoteConfigSettings.minimumFetchInterval = fetchInterval
    remoteConfig.configSettings = remoteConfigSettings
    
    remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate { status, error in

        guard error == nil, status == .successFetchedFromRemote else {
            completionHandler(error)
            return
        }


        completionHandler(nil)
    }
}
```

Thanks